# How to add one data frame below another data frame without any identifiers

Tags: r, merge

I have to dfs that have the same column names in the exact same order like this

```
df1 <-

a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4


df2 <-
a  b  c  d
4  3  2  1
4  3  2  1
4  3  2  1
4  3  2  1
```

I would like to simply merge these dfs by adding df2 below df1 to get df3

```
df3 <- 

    a  b  c  d
    1  2  3  4
    1  2  3  4
    1  2  3  4
    1  2  3  4
    4  3  2  1
    4  3  2  1
    4  3  2  1
    4  3  2  1
```

I tried `merge(df1,df2)` but the result is an empty df.

Comment: Does `rbind(df1, df2)` work?

Comment: Thank you it worked! Cbind does not work due to different row lengths.

Comment: @JjBlevins Yup, `cbind` was a spelling error on my side (that's why I deleted my comment). `rbind` is what you want. Also, take a look at the dupe target link for other options.